# Microsoft Project - How to quick-filter tasks in this week

Tags: ms-project, tools, gantt

As subject, on early Monday, I want to see "what we planned to do in this week". At late Friday, I want to see "what has done/delayed in this week".

However, I can't find how to quick-filter tasks like that. How does one do this?

**"task in this week" in my context:**

1. Task start in previous week (or before) and finish in this week
2. Task start in previous week (or before) and finish in next week (or later)
3. Task start in this week

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check your task bar, top right there should be a pull-down menu you can select type of filtering. You will want to filter by "Date Range", you will then be prompted to enter start date and end date of the range.

I don't know how to get to this through the menus.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

and Here is screen for Microsoft project 2010.
[image: for Microsoft project 2010 :]

Answer (score 1):

What I myself prefer is clicking the AutoFilter button to show the dropdown menu buttons on all of the columns.

[image: Column filter menus are displayed.] 
       
     Assuming you have "Start" and "Finish" columns, you can press the little button on each column to set yourself the start and end dates. 
[image: Here is the drop-down menu expanded.]

If you want something really specific, like a range of start dates, click "Custom...".

[image: You can choose a number of conditional options.]  
      
     My absolute favorite thing to do is to click "Save..." in the custom filter window, and save all of my filters on at that moment to the main filters drop-down menu. What that lets me do is apply the filter while I'm in Calendar view, to print a specific set of tasks in a format that looks great. However, Calendar doesn't seem to always behave properly. 

 
      
Anyway, I hope this helps your organizational endeavors!